# Bootstrap 4 display search box when sticky nav locks in place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 4.

How would I display a search input once the sticky nav locks in-place and remove it when it is not locked in place? I want it to be displayed on the right-hand side of the nave.

I figure this would need to be done with Jquery but I am not a frontend guy so this way above my design capabilities. 
Take a look at the site it's up at www.pricereference.com.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #D84728;
  border-color: #D84728;
  color: white;
}

.btn-success {
  background-color: #D84728;
  border-color: #D84728;
  color: white;
}

.btn-price-reference {
  background-color: #3cc390;
  border-color: #3cc390;
  color: white;
}

.top-header {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.search-box {
  padding-top: .3rem;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #0064b2;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.nav-item a {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Asul', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}


/* Home Page */

.list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 0rem;
  background-color: #3acfef;
  color: white;
}

.list-group-item:first-child h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Kavoon', cursive;
}

.list-group-item {
  font-family: 'Asul', sans-serif;
}

.list-group-item-action:focus,
.list-group-item-action:hover {
  background-color: #D84728;
  color: white;
}

.img-fluid {
  max-height: 320px;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
  color: #3cc390;
  font-family: 'Asul', sans-serif;
}

.carousel-caption h4 {
  color: #3cc390;
  font-family: 'Asul', sans-serif;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: #D84728;
}

.best-sellers {
  padding-top: 1.2rem;
}

.best-sellers h2 {
  color: #3cc390;
  font-family: 'Kavoon', cursive;
}

.popular-products {
  padding-bottom: 1.2rem;
}

.product-title {
  color: #8F8F8E;
  font-family: 'Asul', sans-serif;
}


/*bottom */

.bottom_space {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.detail-buttons {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.social-buttons {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/* footer */

footer {
  background-color: #8F8F8E;
  min-height: 350px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footerleft {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 0 36px;
}

.logofooter {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.footerleft p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.footerleft p i {
  width: 20px;
  color: #999;
}

.paddingtop-bottom {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.footer-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.footer-ul li {
  line-height: 29px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.footer-ul li a {
  color: #D84728;
  transition: color 0.2s linear 0s, background 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.footer-ul i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.footer-ul li a:hover {
  transition: color 0.2s linear 0s, background 0.2s linear 0s;
  color: #ff670f;
}

.social:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
}

.icon-ul {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.icon-ul li {
  line-height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.icon {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.copyright {
  min-height: 40px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.copyright p {
  text-align: left;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.heading7 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #d9d6d6;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.post p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.post p span {
  display: block;
  color: #8f8f8f;
}

.bottom_ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.bottom_ul li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.bottom_ul li:after {
  content: "/";
  color: #FFF;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.bottom_ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="{% block description %}{% endblock %}">
  <meta name="keywords" content="{% block keywords %}{% endblock %}" />
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="qgjJmLV5Fd901rWTMqI3oL119zWfarqGqkfPjvnwATk" />
  <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="1960AF70A1C1582C7B84ECFF511B758A" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavoon" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asul" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9bb4a99f3b.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="{% static " css/bootstrap.min.css " %}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="{% static " css/starter-template.css " %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="top-header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <a href="{% url " home " %}"><img src="http://stackedservers.com/cdn/PRICE_REFERENCE.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center search-box">
        <form method='GET' action='{% url "home" %}' class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="Search" type='text' name='q' placeholder='Search For Products' value='{{ request.GET.q }}' />
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-toggleable-md">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url " home " %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url " products:best_sellers " %}">Best Sellers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url " products:products_all " %}">All Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url " products:all_categories " %}">All Categories</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried in the question. The external site will change over time and no longer be relevant to future readers of this question.

Comment: Update with the HTML code

Comment: @TomMyers, that's hardly enough. You need to transform it into a snippet using the `<>` button, so we can see how it looks. Link any resources (css and js) that are currently applying if you want something that works. Also, you need to include the part that  *"locks (your nav) in-place "*.

Comment: Included linked bootstrap 4 and css

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code of how you can achieve similar feature to reference website.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var $menu = $('#navbar-main');
var menuOffsetY = $menu.offset().top;
function scroll() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= menuOffsetY) {
        $menu.addClass('fixed-top');
    } else {
        $menu.removeClass('fixed-top');
    }


   }

  document.onscroll = scroll;

});
```

```css
body{
 min-height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>    
   </div>
   <div class="col-8">
 <form class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>    
   </div>
  </div>



</nav>
<nav id="navbar-main" class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav> 
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<footer id="footer" class="footer">
  <p class="text-center"><br>This is my big footer, only test. :)</p>
</footer> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can check the output in full screen here https://output.jsbin.com/goqaded

Comment: The OP specifically asked for Bootstrap v4. And you're not placing the search box inside the navbar.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated answer with Bootstrap v4, also made search box visible in smaller screens.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP asked how he can hide the search box when the navbar becomes fixed, without telling or showing how the navbar becomes fixed. As of now, this question is unanswerable.